# How to completely disable os clipboard integration

Tags: os-clipboard

The vim binary shipped with the git for windows package has integration with OS clipboard enabled and I hate it. So many times I attempt to replace a word with something from the clipboard with `cw` + <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>insert</kbd>, only to be frustrated because the `cw` command ruined the clipboard by overwriting with the thing I wanted to replace.

So how do I disable this completely and forever, so that vim never ever interacts with the OS clipboard?

Comment: Have you tried `set clipboard=""` in your vimrc? [`:h g:clipboard`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/provider.txt.html#g%3Aclipboard)

Comment: @statox Make your comment into an answer, it worked (although there is no g:clipboard help entry).

Comment: My bad I used the wrong topic and I didn't realize because `:h g:clipboard` exists in neovim but not in vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the doc for [`:h 'clipboard'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27clipboard%27) it is used to tell to vim to use different system clipboards or none of them. (The behavior is a bit different between vim and neovim).

In your case you want to use no clipboard so put that in your vimrc:

```
set clipboard=""
```

*As Ben pointed out in the comments the `""` is not necessary you can write only `set clipboard=`*

Comment: @D.BenKnoble you're right but I never got used to this syntax, having nothing after a `=` still makes me uncomfortable :)